# buildfire.services.bluetooth.ble only returns test data

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to develop using the BLE api. 
However no matter what I try, I am only getting useless test data back.

A workaround would be possible using Web Bluetooth, however, I can't append a button outside of the plugin iframe.

What would your suggested way of developing with the bluetooth functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you turned on the Bluetooth feature in your plugin.json ? See documentation here https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Low-Energy-Bluetooth-Service

Once that is completed make sure you rebuild your app (hard build) since your app need to request permission to access Bluetooth. If you aren’t prompted when you install the app to allow Bluetooth access, then something isn’t right.

Comment: I would need the App to be native in order for bluetooth to work?
Would it be possible to integrate Web Bluetooth to allow PWA's to also have bluetooth access.

I tried adding Web Bluetooth to the plugin, and unfortunately it gets blocked due to the iframe that the plugin is rendered in